# wandb loops work differently between Jupyter Notebook and Microsoft Visual Studio Code (Pyhton3)

Tags: python, wandb

The following code should loop 3 times. It works three times in Jupyter notbook but only once in VSC. Weird.

```
import wandb
N_EPOCHS=10
batch_size=16
from tqdm import tqdm 
for eachtime in tqdm(range(3)):
     
    wandb.init(project='test',name='TESTWANDB'+'_'+str(eachtime))
    wandb.config = {
                "epochs": N_EPOCHS,
                "batch_size": batch_size
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to each `init` call to create a new run, you should call `wandb.finish()` and that'll explicitly end that run, then you can call `wandb.init` again to start a new run.

Comment: Thx. Then Why I donot need this step in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: This is a known difference in behaviour and we're looking into it. 
In the meantime, if you want the same behaviour outside of Jupyter, you can pass in `reinit=True` to `wandb.init` and it will create a new run every time `wandb.init` is called.